# Is there any cleaner way to write multiple if-statements in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have an if-else structure in Java as follow:

```
                    if (A || B || C){
                        if (A){
                            //Do something
                        }
                        if (B){
                            //Do something
                        }
                        if (C){
                            //Do something
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Do something
                    }
```

I want to know if there is any cleaner and easier way to replace this?

Comment: You do not need the first if statement at all.

Comment: @SebastianK how would you do the last `else ` then? `if (! (A || B || C))` ?

Comment: With a default and switch... see below

Comment: Could you give some more information about the use-case here?  How are `A`, `B` and `C` evaluated?  Are they expected to be mutually exclusive (i.e. at most one of them is set)?  There are multiple ways to do _exactly_ what you've got here put below, but depending where the variables come from there might be more readable ways (lookup from `Map`, array of callbacks, etc.).

Comment: @Alex Wang it would also be useful to know 1) If the `A`, `B` and `C` are exclusive (only one can be true) and 2) if "Do something" is always the same piece of code.

Comment: @Dorian Gray Hi in my case A, B and C are independent on each other and "Do something" is not the same under different conditions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If A,B and C are conditions which are expensive to evaluate, you could use an additional flag to make sure they are only evaluated once:

```
boolean found = false;
if (A) {
    //Do something
    found = true;
}
if (B){
    //Do something
    found = true;
}
if (C){
    //Do something
    found = true;
}
if (!found) {
    //Do something
}
```

Otherwise (i.e. if they are not expensive to evaluate), I'd keep your current conditions.

Comment: Thanks I think this can reduce the time complexity because in my case, A, B, C are some complexed conditions

Comment: As a matter of personal preference, I would put `found = true;` first in the conditionals, in order that it's easy to see that you are setting the flag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
if (A) {
  // do A
}
if (B) {
  // do B
}
if (C) {
  // do C
}
if (! (A || B || C)) {
  // do "neither A or B or C"
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192860/discussion-on-answer-by-bart-friederichs-is-there-any-cleaner-way-to-write-multi).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I think what you have is fine, you *could* do it like this:

```
boolean d = false;
if (d |= A) { ... }
if (d |= B) { ... }
if (d |= C) { ... }
if (!d) {
  // What to do if A..C are all false.
}
```

This will set `d` to true if any of the conditions are matched (`d` is for "did something").

Comment: @BartFriederichs to each his own. As I say: I think the existing code is fine.

Comment: @AndyTurner Just note that you would stoll have to initialize `boolean d = false;`, or it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Just one more possible solution:

```
public class ABC {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ABC.class);

    @Test
    public void abc() {
        boolean A = true;
        boolean B = false;
        boolean C = true;

        boolean abcProcessed = false;

        abcProcessed |= process(A, () -> {
            // Do something for A
            log.debug("A");
        });
        abcProcessed |= process(B, () -> {
            // Do something for B
            log.debug("B");
        });
        abcProcessed |= process(C, () -> {
            // Do something for B
            log.debug("C");
        });

        if (!abcProcessed) {
            // Do something for !(A||B||C)
            log.debug("!(A||B||C)");
        }
    }

    private boolean process(boolean flag, DoSomethingInterface doSomethingInterface) {
        // check condition
        if (flag) {
            // execute code specific for condition
            doSomethingInterface.doSomething();
            // return true (processed)
            return true;
        }

        // return false (not processed)
        return false;
    }

    public interface DoSomethingInterface {

        // code specific for condition
        void doSomething();
    }
}
```

An idea is to move condition checking and related code to separate method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use else if conditions:

```
if(A){

}else if(B){

}else if(C){

}else if(D){

}
```

But, if you have many conditions like A,B,C etc it feels that something wrong with  logic of your program

Comment: No, you cannot use it, as there might be `A = true, B = true, C = false`, Your code will also execute the first case then. That's not the same as in the original post.